# jQuery select main document and all iframes documents within the main document (with one selection)

Tags: javascript, iframe, jquery

I'm trying to trigger an on mousemove event on the main document + all iframes in the page. I can achieve this with 2 selections :

```
$(document).on( "mousemove", handler );

$("iframe").contents().on( "mousemove", handler );
```

Can I do this with one selection?

I tried this, but is only working for the main document:

```
$(document,$("iframe").contents()).on( "mousemove", handler );
```

Thanks

Comment: what about `$(document).contents().on( "mousemove", handler )`

Comment: @Murali I just tried and only works for the main document.

Comment: @Doua, I'm not sure you can do that. IIRC jQuery objects store the document all the elements in the set belong to, so I don't think you can mix elements from different documents in the same jQuery object.